# Integrate with WebSphere Web Service in .Net

Tags: .net, soap, websphere

I’m using .Net, C#...the usual.

Got a client web service to implement (WebSphere, not exposing wsdl, soap…was a total pain to get it working since I know near to nothing of any of these)

I eventually got to use the service by instead of adding a service reference, adding a web service reference. 
Because the service does not expose its wsdl, but the client supplied me the wsdl file, I specified the file path as service location, and then edited the app config.

All working fine, until the client had to add security today and I now have to specify a username and password to call their service and I’m clueless.

A few extract from the client’s IT guy’s mails for what it might help (mostly greek to me):

“We are going to secure the services using the industry standard WS-Security User Name Token”
“Use the following credentials for the WS-Security UNT”

All I really can do here is supply my “demo code” which worked before the security have been added on their side:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="ABCD.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <applicationSettings>
        <ABCD_Login.Properties.Settings>
          <setting name="ABCD_Login_AccessControlService_AccessControlService"
                serializeAs="String">
            <value>https://aaa.bbb.com/something/SecurityFacadeService/AccessControlService</value>
          </setting>
        <ABCD_Login.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

---

```
var client = new AccessControlService();
bool validUser = client.validate(username, password);
```

But now I have no clue where and how to set the username / password for calling the service (not the username / password for the validate method)

Anyone? Big Please!

Answer (score 0):

You need configure WS-Security User Name Token (UNT).

This is the good article for you: [UNT](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1001_chung/1001_chung.html)